# Nominativ or Akkusativ

Tags: translation, german-to-english, accusative, nominative

I was reading a story book where I found this

> ... und natürlich viele Münchner, die wie **er** den Samstagnachmittag
>   hier genießen.

that translates in English to:

> ... and, of course, many people from Munich who, like **him**, enjoy the
>   Saturday afternoon here.

My question is, why the Nominative pronomen **er** is used in the above example instead of Akkusativ Personalpronomen **ihm**? As far as I understand **er** stands for **he** in English and **ihm** stands for **him**.

Comment: The Akkusativ personal pronoun of er would be **ihn**. Ihm is the Dativ pronoun. Both Akkusativ and Dativ pronoun can be translated as him. "Ich sehe ihn." (I see him). "Ich gebe ihm ein Geschenk." (I give him a present).

Comment: @infinitezero oh yeah, just mixed up ihn and ihm in my mind. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: The real question should be why it is "like **him**" in English and not "like **he**". "er genießt - viele Münchner genießen", "many people enjoy - he enjoys". So, why "like **him**"?..

Comment: Why would it be Akkusativ? It is the subject of the subordinate clause, why would you use Akkusativ (hint, using *him* in English for the above is wrong).

Comment: @gented are you sure using *him* is wrong? I've checked [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=who+like+him%2C+who+like+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwho%20like%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwho%20like%20he%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwho%20like%20him%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwho%20like%20he%3B%2Cc0) and while the hits for "who like him" also include constructions like "It would be truer to say that people *who like him* seem to dwell on his shortcomings", it also includes usages like this question.

Comment: *him* is definitely used in colloquial speech (this is probably the reason why there are so many N-grams present), as well as using *me* instead of *I* is becoming somehow the norm; this said, as long as the nominal part of the clause plays the role of the subject, it must be in the subject case.

Comment: @gented: No, you must be thinking of "as". "Like" in English is standardly treated as a preposition that takes the objective case (like "with" or "to").

Answer (score 17, accepted):

'like' functions as a preposition in this English sentence, and while (all?) prepositions in German decline the noun they're acting on, the word 'wie' *is not a preposition*. Rather, it is a [conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_(grammar)); in this case, while your translation is more idiomatic, the grammar function of 'wie' corresponds more to the English 'as':

> ... and, of course, many people from Munich who, as he, enjoy the Saturday afternoon here.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and just to supplement Glorfindel's answer with a little further explanation:

The *er* in the German sentence is not only not the object of a preposition (as already explained), but it is the subject, naturally nominative, of a verb that has been left implicit, since the conjunction normally introduces a *clause*. A close English equivalent completed with the corresponding verb would be:

> ... and, of course, many people from Munich who enjoy the Saturday
>   afternoon here, as he *does*.